Am I fetching/calculating net liquidity wrong? (Uniswap V3)
I am querying data from the PEPE/ETH pool (pool id: 0x11950d141EcB863F01007AdD7D1A342041227b58). I posted all my code below to query and find the cumulative/active liquidity at each tick in the input space. I want to recreate the liquidity distribution. However, in the data I have noticed some of the values for the cumulative/active liquidity is negative, which seems wrong. Is there something wrong with this query? I am using this subgraph for the query (https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraphs/5zvR82QoaXYFyDEKLZ9t6v9adgnptxYpKpSbxtgVENFV?view=Query&chain=arbitrum-one). I am also aware of a similar question asked here (How to Accurately Compute Tick Liquidity in Uniswap V3?). I am accumulating the liquidity from lower to higher ticks so as in the answer I am just adding the liquidity. I have also tried this line to obtain the cumulative liquidity: df['liquidityNet'].cumsum() and that also results in negative values. Another note: this doesn't seem to be a problem when I was querying the WBTC/ETH pool (pool id: 0xCBCdF9626bC03E24f779434178A73a0B4bad62eD)
def get_hourly_pool_data(pool_address):
skip = 0
batch_size = 1000
timestamp = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
all_ticks = []
pool_data = None
cumulative_liquidity = 0

while True:
    query = """
    {
        pool(id: "%s") {
            id
            tick
            ticks(first: %d, skip: %d, orderBy: tickIdx, orderDirection: asc) {
                tickIdx
                liquidityNet
            }
        }
    }
    """ % (pool_address, batch_size, skip)
    print(query)

    try:
        response = requests.post(
            GRAPH_API_URL,
            json={'query': query},
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()['data']['pool']
            
            if pool_data is None:
                pool_data = {
                    "id": data['id'],
                    "tick": data['tick']
                }
            
            ticks = data['ticks']
            if not ticks:
                break
            tick_data = []
            for tick in ticks:
                print(tick)
                cumulative_liquidity += int(tick['liquidityNet'])
                tick_data.append({
                    "tickIdx": tick['tickIdx'],
                    "liquidityNet": tick['liquidityNet'],
                    "cumulative_liquidity": cumulative_liquidity
                })
            all_ticks.extend(tick_data)
            skip += batch_size
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(all_ticks)

df['timestamp'] = timestamp
df['current_tick'] = pool_data['tick']
df['pool_id'] = pool_data['id']

df['tickIdx'] = df['tickIdx'].astype(int)
df['cumulative_liquidity'] = df['cumulative_liquidity'].astype(float)
df['liquidityNet'] = df['liquidityNet'].astype(float)
# Calculate cumulative liquidity
df = df.sort_values('tickIdx')


The issue with negative cumulative liquidity values likely comes from either how you're processing liquidityNet or an inconsistency in the tick data from the subgraph. Here’s how you can fix it:

Ensure Ticks Are Sorted
liquidityNet must be accumulated in ascending order of tickIdx. Add this line after building your DataFrame:
df = df.sort_values('tickIdx')


Initialize Cumulative Liquidity Correctly
If you're starting with cumulative_liquidity = 0, that's fine only if the queried ticks fully cover the active range of the pool. Otherwise, you need to start from the pool's current liquidity. Fetch the pool's current total liquidity from its on-chain state if necessary.

Validate and Debug Tick Data
Print the liquidityNet values to identify anomalies:
print(df[['tickIdx', 'liquidityNet', 'cumulative_liquidity']])

Large or unexpected negative values in liquidityNet might indicate an issue with the subgraph data. If this happens, consider cross-checking with on-chain data or querying the pool state directly using the Uniswap V3 contract.

Exclude Out-of-Bounds Ticks
Ensure you're only processing ticks within the pool's active range:
df = df[df['tickIdx'] >= min_tick]
df = df[df['tickIdx'] <= max_tick]



If these steps don’t resolve the issue, there may be a problem with the subgraph syncing for the PEPE/ETH pool. Try testing with another pool or querying data directly from the Uniswap V3 smart contracts.

So for #1 I sorted the ticks and then calculated the cumulative liquidity I get the same numbers. For #2 and #4 I think the code should be getting all the ticks by skipping in batches and starting at the first tick right? I'm a little unclear since I don't see any documentation but it seems to be working as the first tick fetched is -887220. For #3 there are extremely large liquidityNet values fetched:
Largest positive liquidity: 28075182570925980469738372 at tick -187320
Largest negative liquidity: -32896388771746811927331205 at tick -184500
However I verified this with the contract.

Am I understanding something wrong about the api? I am basically trying to build up the liquidity distribution of the pool across all tick ranges. Do you know of a better way to do this?
